# How to route To different MasterPages in sharepoint?

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, master-page, custom-masterpage

I 'm trying to create a HttpModule that allows to route to different MasterPage preInt event. 
 I' not an Expert about MasterPages.  I'm trying to nderstand about MasterPages Token. 
 I knows there are three type: custom and Default. 
 In this tutorial 
I found this  code :

```
void page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page page = sender as Page;
        string pageNo = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MasterPageNo"];




        if (page != null)
        {
            if (pageNo.Equals("1"))
            {
                page.MasterPageFile = "~masterurl/custom.master";
                if (SPContext.Current != null)
                {
                    SPContext.Current.Web.CustomMasterUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/custom1.master";
                }
            }
            else if (pageNo.Equals("2"))
            {
                page.MasterPageFile = "~masterurl/custom.master";
                if (SPContext.Current != null)
                {
                    SPContext.Current.Web.CustomMasterUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/custom2.master";
                }


            }
            else
            {
                page.MasterPageFile = "~masterurl/default.master";
                if (SPContext.Current != null)
                {
                    SPContext.Current.Web.MasterUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/default.master";
                }
            }


        }
```

In Sharepoint , I have three MasterPages :

-Default.Master
-GeneraliTeamSite.MasterPage.Master
-GeneraliTeamSiteWiki.MasterPage.Master.master

With Sp Designer, I have set Default.master as Default, GeneraliTeamSite.MasterPage.Master as Custom.
Now if i Run the page, I got this exception :

```
The file '/_layouts/~masterurl/custom.master' does not exist.   at System.Web.UI.Util.CheckVirtualFileExists(VirtualPath virtualPath) 
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) 
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) 
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) 
   at System.Web.UI.MasterPage.CreateMaster(TemplateControl owner, HttpContext context, VirtualPath masterPageFile, IDictionary contentTemplateCollection) 
   at System.Web.UI.Page.get_Master() 
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ApplyMasterPage() 
   at System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit() 
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is some code I've used in the past to dynamically set the masterpage based on a querystring in the URL.

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnPreInit(e);
    if (this.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("frame=true")) {
        this.MasterPageFile = "framed.master";
    }
}
```

http://mike-greene.com/2011/10/dynamic-master-page-logic/

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the code looks very good, although i noticed one error:

Here is how to set the new masterpage:

```
page.MasterPageFile="~/_catalogs/masterpage/v4_minimal.master"
```

Because what you did is:

```
page.MasterPageFile = "~masterurl/custom.master";
```

And this will not work due to a wrong path ...

Here is the full example, but check for the correct path ...

```
if (page.MasterPageFile != null)
{
    page.MasterPageFile = "~/_catalogs/masterpage/custom.master";
    if (pageNo.Equals("1"))
    {
        if (SPContext.Current != null)
        {
            SPContext.Current.Web.CustomMasterUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/custom1.master";
        }
    }
    else if (pageNo.Equals("2"))
    {
        if (SPContext.Current != null)
        {
            SPContext.Current.Web.CustomMasterUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/custom2.master";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        page.MasterPageFile = "~/_catalogs/masterpage/default.master";
        if (SPContext.Current != null)
        {
            SPContext.Current.Web.MasterUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/default.master";
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it was usefull!

Happy coding!

Comment: Unfortunately it still not working. MEssage error is  : "The file /_catalogs/masterpage/custom.master does not exist. "  Do you know how should I do to debugg attaching to iis?  I do this well but breakpoint doesn't  hit!!!